# Calling one page in another makes website slow?

Tags: php, html, web

I am making a website where I have to keep track of logged in users. So in every PHP document, I have written code to connect to the database. If I write the database connecting code in one php document and call it in other PHP documents, will it make my page slow?

Instead of putting all features on one page, what if I design features in different pages and call all features on one page? Will it a slow downloading speed of a website?

Comment: In what way are you calling this piece of code? Include?

Comment: Please update this question with some sample code so that someone can recreate the issue. SO provides some tips on how to do this at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this will help all of us help you!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the answer is yes; but it’s so minuscule that there’s no reason to worry about it. What you gain, on the other hand, is priceless. You have just discovered a principle called DRY— Don’t Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would certainly have *some* impact, but this should be weighed against the benefits of code organization.  In this case, I'd *strongly* err on the side of code organization, so I suggest break up your logic into multiple files.  A few points in favor of this approach:

- Keep in mind that you are talking server-side only.  That means the delay comes from opening local files on the server, rather than, say, sending HTTP requests.  This is a *very* fast operation on any modern computer.
- "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Until you actually have speed issues, bending backwards for optimization's sake is universally considered a bad idea.  This is because optimization tends to obfuscate code while rarely providing appreciable speed benefits.  This bogs down developer comprehension and increases the likelyhood of bugs.
- And, as Andreas pointed out, code reuse is king.  Rewriting the same code in multiple places means that making a change requires duplicating that change in all those places, which takes time and (again) increases the likelyhood of bugs.

Comment: Not to mention of you need to add/change something in the code. Having it all in one place is a little bit easier than changing it in all files.

Comment: You're welcome.  And if you like the answer then it'd be great to have it accepted.